# Tensorflow - Histogram Loss Function

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, histogram, scikit-image

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm trying to design a Loss Function to account for the difference in the 3-Channel Histogram of the Input image and the Output image.

I know the L1 loss in Tensorflow is like `tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(Output- Input)` but don't know how to write it to compare Histograms.

Thanks...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Histogram"? Are you trying to find the difference between two vectors?

Comment: I want to extract the 3-channel RGB histogram of images (which will be three [0-255] vectors), find the distance between their histograms and optimize this distance. I don't know if I can use OpenCV to get the histograms (which gives back numpy vectors) and then use Tensorflow L1 loss (as mentioned in the post) or if I should do all of the calculations with Tensorflow ops so that it could optimize the network and do proper back propagation and gradient descent. Thanks...

Comment: It will work like you've written it, I think. You can sum the differences between each histogram.

Comment: It's been my impression that if I don't use TensorFlow's (or Theano's) own operations to do the calculations for the loss, it will not be backpropagated properly... so was I wrong? can I do all the calculations without Tensorflow's own operations (like in OpenCV) and just use the final output (the 2 Histogram vectors from OpenCV) in the Tensorflow L1 loss? or I should do the Histogram matching WITH Tensorflow's operations?

Comment: You're right about back propagation, but they use operator overloading to allow for things like `a - b` if `a` and `b` are Tensors or Variables or whatever.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson - would you be willing to upgrade your comments to an answer so it's recorded?  Thanks!